# AC3, add PropertyChangeEvent event to an object

Tags: actionscript, event-handling

im looking for a way to add an PropertyChangeEvent to an object that I have defined. The goal is to raise a change event when any of the property of the object is been changed.

so i can do something like the following

```
var newItem:MyObject = new MyObject();
newItem.addEventListener(event.PropertyChangeEvent, myO_PropertyChangeHandler);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyObject extends EventDispatcher
{
    public function doSomething() :void
    {
        // change values, and dispatch event
        dispatchEvent( PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent( this, "myProperty", oldValue, newValue ) );
    }
}
```

If you can't extend `EventDispatcher` because your object extends something else, and if that super class isn't already a subtype of `EventDispatcher` or implements `IEventDispatcher` (which includes *most* types), you need to implement `IEventDispatcher` manually. See the help page for `IEventDispatcher` for example code on how you do that (i.e. with an internal `EventDispatcher` doing the actual job).

Comment: doing it this way would work, and i guess you probably don't need to implements IEventDispatcher? but what I am looking for is a way that i don't have to do raise event in every setter. something that would work on a String property as well rather than getter/setter. If this explains my intention more clearly.

Comment: Well, that's not how it works. ActionScript cannot magically observe your properties.. If you want a PropertyChangeEvent to fire every time a property is changed, you will need to tell ActionScript for every single property to dispatch such an event.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for the [Bindable](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html#159635) Meta tag.